# How can I delay page transition in jQuery Mobile until page data is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a mobile single-page web application that is built using jquery-mobile (jqm) and knockout. The application itself has multiple pages but they are all contained within a single HTML document.

Problem: after changing my "create view model for page" from sync to async behavior, I have the problem that jquery-mobile fires its events before the data is ready.

Background: up until recently I had been working with sample data, basically a huge JSON blob, and everything worked smoothly. With the new async composition of view models from various sources, data is not ready immediately and my "buildViewModel" method takes a continuation callback instead of just synchronously returning data.

I'm subscribing to the pagebeforecreate and pagebeforechange events, and fire off the code to populate the viewmodel here. The problem is that after returning from the event handler, jqm triggers the remaining chain of events before the data is available. This causes a page transition to an unprepared page, which is undesirable.

I have tried to call `event.preventDefault` in all of the before-events and manually calling $.mobile.changePage once the page is ready to be a) enhanced and b) the page transition to occur, but without any luck.

I've scanned the jquery-mobile source, but couldn't spot anything that looked like it would allow me to delay the `pagebeforeshow` event, which is essentially what I need in order to be able to render the page properly.

How can I ensure that 1) data is available and 2) knockout has been applied to perform initial DOM manipulations, before jquery-mobile attempts to enhance the page and before it executes the in-transition to the page?

I also considered using synchronous ajax to fetch resources, but this will (I think) not work for resources loaded from the device (using PhoneGap/Cordova), and has other negative consequences that I'd like to avoid.

FWIW, I'd like to avoid having to manually handle all navigation events by wiring up click-handlers everywhere, but I'm open to all solutions if need be.

Apologies if this is a duplicate; I've searched and read a ton of questions, but not found an answer or question that was quite the same. It just sounds incredible that I would be the first to hit this problem, as I imagine it is a common scenario..

Update: clarified problem scenario description.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this exact same problem.

The only solution I've been able to come up with is to write a [custom transition handler](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-customtransitions.html) that defers starting the transition until the Ajax request completes.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdiamond/9yYae/) showing the technique. The fiddle doesn't use Knockout, but does show how to defer the transition.

Basically, since `$.ajax()` returns a promise, I can pipe that into the promise returned by the default transition handler and return it from my new handler.

In my pagebeforeshow handler, I attach the Ajax promise to the page so that the transition handler has access to it. Not sure if this is the best way, but I liked it better than using a global variable.

The only thing I didn't like about this is that it delays the start of the transition until the Ajax response arrives so it could feel like the page has "hung" to the user making them click again. Manually showing the loading message makes it feel a bit more responsive.

Hope this helps and please let me know if you find a better solution!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've got this working locally now, and will stick with it misbehaves when executed on an actual device. Apologies for the delay, it took me a while to get back to the project after returning from vacation. I'll keep you posted if I run into problems; meanwhile, if you improve on the solution or spot troubles, I'd appreciate a heads-up :)

Comment: I have the same issue with backbone and jqmobile and this sounds perfect. It seems so obvious now!

Comment: I have started working with your solution successfully until I upgraded jquerymobile to 1.4. From then on I get an error 'Uncaught TypeErro: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined. I have run your exact fiddle code with 1.4, the only difference I found is that the oldDefaultTransitionHandler has changed from the usual `function ( name, reverse, $to, $from )...` to an enigmatic function `function () { this.init.apply(this, arguments)};` I tried finding documentation on custom transitions in 1.4 to see if anything changed but could not find any. Any idea how to solve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Delaying the transition to a new page until its content is ready is a very common issue when facing dynamic content in jQuery Mobile. The most convenient ways to address this are:

- Instead of classic href type navigation, base the links on "click" actions that will first retrieve the content, build a new page in the DOM, and then initiate a transition to this new page through `$.mobile.changePage`. The advantage of this approach is that it is easy to put in place, the disadvantage is that you do not navigate with classic `href` links
- Bind the `pagebeforechange` event at the document level to detect if upon navigation the target page is one of your page that should contain dynamic content. In such a case, you can prevent default navigation from happening, take your time to generate the page, and transition upon success. This is described in the JQM docs [on dynamically injected content](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html). The advantage is that you can still rely on standard `href` links navigation, but it requires a bit more code and design upstream to properly detect and act upon navigation to the pages.

  ```
  $(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
      if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
           if ( data.toPage === "myDynamicPageName" ) {
               e.preventDefault(); //used to stop transition to the page (for now)

               /*
                  Here you can make your ajax call
                  In you callback, once you have generated the page you can call
                  $.mobile.changePage
                  (you can pass the Div of the new page instead of its name as
                  the changepage parameter to avoid interrupting again the page change) 
               */
            }
        }
  });
  ```

Comment: I ended up using Jason's solution, which is much the same concept but nicely integrated by simply overriding the default jqm page transition handler. With this approach I did not need to add click handlers or disable any of jqm's built-in functionality, so am pretty happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

Set your link to call a "load" function instead of doing a page transition. In your load function, display the "loading message" and make the JSON call. Finally, in the JSON callback function, change *page* to **page2**

The load function:

```
function loadPage2() {
    /* show wait page */
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
            text: 'Loading massively huge dataset',
            textVisible: true
    });

     /* perform JSON call then call callback */
 }
```

Callback function

```
function callback() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
}
```

Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8w7PM/

Note that if you don't want users to be able to update input fields in Page 1 while waiting, introduce a "wait page" between page 1 and page 2, with the init of "wait page" doing the same as "loadPage2".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to fire again for all widget which you want to bind the data from response to

For example, you will have to invoke `trigger` with `create` or `refrest`event for the element
`$("#element").trigger('create');`
JQuery Mobile will bind all default events to the element as it is

--- EDIT ---

I just created a sample code, I think it's same your issue, please try the link http://jsfiddle.net/ndkhoiits/BneqW/embedded/result/

Before rending the data, we have to invoke to service to get them for displaying, that why all events binded by jqm will be removed then.

I have a workaround for this, don't make jqm fire anything on the element, we'll trigger it after all data is binded by knockoutjs
Let try the fixed version
http://jsfiddle.net/ndkhoiits/c5a2b/embedded/result/

This is the code http://jsfiddle.net/ndkhoiits/c5a2b/

Comment: The code sample shows how to make jqm enhance existing DOM content, such as when you have added items to a list or fetched data from a server. That is not my problem. My problem is how to deal with navigation between pages. I can hook the pagebeforechange/pagebeforeshow/pagecreate events, but if I perform an ajax request in e.g. pagebeforechange then pagebeforeshow will have fired before the success callback for the ajax request returns, which makes jqm transition to an unprepared page. I would like to delay this transition until the page is ready to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small jQuery Mobile / KnockoutJS application and have struggled with the very same issue. My app contains about 5 pages. All are contained in a single physical HTML document with the standard `<div data-role="page">` markup separating individual pages.

I finally went with click based navigation and fire `$.mobile.changePage()` as the result of `$.ajax` success.

One of the downsides to this technique is that you will lose your button highlighting when relying on `onclick` vs `href` attributes. See my related post: [href vs scripted page transitions and button highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953768/)

I later chose to supply both and rely on the `href` to perform the navigation while using `onclick` to invoke my JavaScript logic to load ViewModels etc. The only place that I have found this to be an issue is when there is possible validation required on the source page. If it fails, the transition has already started and the UI then flashes back to the source page. Ugly but this only happens in limited instance within my app.

I don't think any of this is specific to Knockout. My exact solution may present issues for you in that your navigation is likely to complete before your model is fully loaded but if you rely on `$.mobile.changePage()`, it should all work and hide your page until after it is loaded. The transitions should work fine.

```
<a href="#MyNewPage" data-bind="click:LoadNewPage" data-role="button">
    Load Page
</a>

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: requestData,
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // use either href or changePage but not both
        $.mobile.changePage("#NewPage");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("AJAX Error. Status: " + textStatus);
        // jqXHR.status
        // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You should place the code for the page transition in a success function on the AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"request-url",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response){
        // Add Transition Code Here
    }  
});
```

Comment: Please see comment on Khoi's post.

Comment: try adding this to the "pagebeforechange" event.

'queue(function(next){  
   $.ajax({
    url:"request-url",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response){
        next();
    }  
  });
});'

Comment: queue? that isn't a function in jqm, and as such quite unlikely to have any impact on the behavior of jqm.

Comment: @MortenMertner It's a jquery function, you should use it like '$(element).queue(...)'

Comment: jqm does not use the method anywhere in its source (it uses an internal pageTransitionQueue array), but it does (afaik) use jquery to perform the transitions, so this could actually work. Sadly, I'm leaving for Vegas tomorrow morning, so probably won't find time to try it out before I leave. Will post back if I manage to squeeze it in, thanks!